# How to arrange elements in Vuejs component

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component in Vue like this:

Tags.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-chip
      v-for="tag in tags"
      :key="tag"
      class="ma-2"
      label
      x-small
      color="blue"
      text-color="white"
    >
      {{ tag }}
    </v-chip>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Tags',
  props: {
    tags: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => ['Empty'],
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

This is the result

[image]

How can I make them appear one below the other instead of side by side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another solution without css:

I use  tag https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/chip-groups/

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <v-chip-group column active-class="primary--text">
      <v-chip
        v-for="tag in tags"
        :key="tag"
        class="ma-2"
        outlined
        x-small
        color="blue"
        text-color="blue"
      >
        {{ tag }}
      </v-chip>
    </v-chip-group>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Tags',
  props: {
    tags: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => ['Empty'],
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be a css questions. Add a class "container" for the wrapper div and put some css into it. You can use `flex-box`

```
<div class="container">
    <v-chip
      v-for="tag in tags"
      :key="tag"
      class="ma-2"
      label
      x-small
      color="blue"
      text-color="white"
    >
      {{ tag }}
    </v-chip>
  </div>



<style lang="scss" scoped>
.container{
  display: flex,
  flex-direction: 'column'
 }
</style>
```